# Offload data from SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have Azure SQL database which stores ~1 million rows per week in a single table (time series data). It has become hard to manage the data due to it's size. I have to rebuild indexes daily to be able to execute queries in less than a second.

I am looking for a way to offload most of the data away from active table/database. For daily operations my application needs only last 2 millions of rows. However, I still need all of the data for historical analysis, so deleting it is not an option.

What would be the best way to deal with it? Most desirable option would be use of some (inexpensive) Azure service, storage. I was considering writing a script that would automatically move data to another database/table but that is really last option. I would rather use a service that was made for this exact purpose, if there exists one.

Comment: What kind of queries? You could leave the DB as is then load the 2 million rows into Azure Analysis Services or just into Power BI and report off that.

Comment: `SELECT` queries which are passed to the code and processed there.

Comment: So basically you just want to support any adhoc select query within the last two million records. You may want to look into Power BI and see if it fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using Table Partitioning as explained in [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3494/azure-sql-database--table-partitioning/) article. There are many benefits of partitioning large tables. You can speed up loading and archiving of data, you can perform maintenance operations on individual partitions instead of the whole table, and you may be able to improve query performance. Test on your scenario to see if partitioning can help speed up queries.